# What widget should I use for center text and left-aside button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am making layout for flutter application

What I want to do is

```
 -----------------------
|[i]      [text]        |
|                       |
```

Icon should be the left (padding 5px)
And text should be the center of screen.

At first I should use the `Column`

However my layout is not the same proportion

It might be simple though , how can I make it??

Comment: do you mean you want to make a vertical list of such combinations (an icon + the text) ?

Comment: Hey, please check out my answer as well. I hope this will add some thing great to your knowledge as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Stack()` is one of the many options that you can use. Something like this:

```
Stack(
  children:<Widget>[
    Padding(
       padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
       child: Icon(Icons.info),
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Text("I'm on the top and centered."),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is something like this..

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.info),
              Text('text'),
              Opacity(opacity: 0, child: Icon(Icons.info)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.info),
              Text('second text'),
              Opacity(opacity: 0, child: Icon(Icons.info)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It can solve more complex matters.I must need this for further development. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late, but I want this answer to be there, if some one would find it better for the development purposes in future time.

We can make a reusable widget, which we can use it inside the main widget. The widget will accept `text`, and `icon` to be passed when called

```
  // IconData is the data type for the icons
  Widget myWidget(String text, IconData icon) => Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      // this will be used a left-padding param
      SizedBox(width: 20.0),
      // using it here
      Icon(icon, size: 28.0, color: Colors.greenAccent),
      SizedBox(width: 5.0),
      // this will take the remaining space, and then center the child
      Expanded(child: Center(child: Text(text)))
    ]
  );
```

To use in the main Widget, just do like this:

```
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            // calling our widget here
            myWidget('FirstText', Icons.alarm),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0), // this is used as a top margin
            myWidget('SecondText', Icons.notifications)
          ]
        )
```

If you wanna check out the sources which I used, please see:

- [Expanded class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)
- [SizedBox class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html)

The result you will get is this:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

This was an answer I gave a while ago for this same issue, but the other situation was vertical (a Column) instead of horizontal (a Row). Just swap the Row and Columns out for a Column and Rows in this example and you'll get the idea.

My code has grey added in order to show the difference between the two approaches.

A Stack will work, but it's overkill for this, this kind of problem is part of why we have Expandeds and Flexibles. The trick is to use three Flexibles (2 Expandeds and a Spacer). Put the Spacer on top. It and the bottom Expanded must have the same flex value in order to center the middle Expanded.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CenteringOneItemWithAnotherItemInTheColumn extends StatelessWidget {
  const CenteringOneItemWithAnotherItemInTheColumn({
    Key key,
  }) : super(
    key: key,
  );

  /// Adjust these values as needed
  final int sameFlexValueTopAndBottom = 40; // 40%
  final int middleFlexValue = 20; // 20%

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Column Alignment Question'),
      ),
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Spacer(),
              const Text(
                'Cent',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 64,
                ),
              ),
              const Spacer(),
              const Text(
                'Bot',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 64,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              /// The key is to have the Spacer and the bottom Expanded
              /// use the same value for flex. That will cause the middle
              /// child of the Column to be centered vertically.
              Expanded(
                flex: sameFlexValueTopAndBottom,
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.grey[300],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: middleFlexValue,
                child: const Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    'Cent',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 64,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: sameFlexValueTopAndBottom,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.grey[300],
                  child: const Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Text(
                      'Bot',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 64,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```